# On which level you acquire followers in D&D: Neverwinter?

Tags: neverwinter

I know that in few missions followers are required but I'm at level 11 and I can't find this information when I will be able to play with my own "bot"

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: They're called "companions" not "followers."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At level 16, the quest A Companion will be available in the level-up unlock menu, or else just by talking to Sgt. Knox. Over the course of this quest, you will get your first companion for free, and after that, you can buy or otherwise acquire more.

Comment: Each basic companion can be bought at the same place you complete that quest for 2 gold pieces

Comment: To add updated information, once you have one companion, you can start doing Sword Coast Adventures. During the tutorial dungeons, you'll earn a free second companion right away!